# How do I create a border around two or more views in Android?

Tags: android-layout

I have a TextView and an EditText in a RelativeLayout. I'd like to create a border behind them with a white background, like a card. I have a few more complex examples, with images and text as well.

[image: The UI I want to see]

The only way I can think of to do this is to introduce multiple nested ViewGroups (say another RelativeLayout), so each card is a ViewGroup which contains the two other Views, and automatically sizes correctly and has a border set.

However, this ends up with a view hierarchy like:

- RelativeLayout

  - RelativeLayout

    - TextView
    - EditView
  - RelativeLayout

    - TextView
    - EditView
  - RelativeLayout

    - ImageView
    - TextView
    - TextView
    - Button

etc

Which seems excessive and potentially problematic, particularly if I end up having nested cards.

Apart from changing the RelativeLayouts for LinearLayouts (which I imagine won't have a large impact), is there any way of simplifying this layout hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is ok according to Google to have up to 6 or 7 nested layouts without a need to worry.

Think of the gmail application. each mail is consisted of (at least 1) ViewGroup that is displayed in a listView which is probably nested inside another (at least 1) ViewGroup...

In short, I think your hierarchy is ok

Comment: Do you have a reference for this from Google (where you say "according to Google")? If so, I'd accept your answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to find it :) but you can inspect the performance of your layout using Android's hierarchyviewer tool. see: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html